# Passive, present perfect continuous, past simple

Tags: grammar

I have been going down my path for few years. I am still going down and find new things. And now I am telling a story about it and how my path started in the past. What to use?

how my path started?

how my path is started?

how my path has started?

how my path was started?

Comment: The first one is fine.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking to use second one. But the first one makes sense. It started and that's it.

Comment: Simplicity is a virtue. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the above seems to be grammatical in contemporary English. You should probably say:

> How did my path start?

Comment: I only can not see the difference between the first one in my list and the way you suggested.

Comment: @Sasha: Yours is wrong. In English you cannot ask a question that way. It might be okay in indirect questions, but that's a totally different thing.

Comment: Still confused. It is indirect question. I am telling a story about my path on which I find new things. Then I want to bring a reader to the point how my path was/is started. So I put this question not to ask anybody about my path but to tell how it was started. I want to use passive voice in this question. How my path is started? Is that correct?

Comment: @Sasha Indirect questions don't end with a question mark. An indirect question might be something like: *I wonder how my path started.*